# A Trivial Pursuit #23 (Science and Nature 4/4): Making Things Difficult

Tags: word, crosswords, science, animals

<sub>This is part 23 of [A Trivial Pursuit](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a60644%20is%3aq%20%22a%20trivial%20pursuit%22&searchOn=3), a 25-part puzzle hunt. Each part is solvable on its own, with the exception of the meta-puzzle at the end.</sub>

---

Here is a crossword for you to solve... Actually, here are *two* crosswords for you to solve.

And here are two lists of clues for the words that complete these grids... But the lists have been combined, and the same-numbered clues ordered alphabetically by their solutions, thereby obfuscating which clue corresponds to which grid.

Fortunately, the clues are straightforward definitions, and not cryptic-style... Ah, but in each pair of clues one word (with a connection to science or nature) has been omitted, and you'll need to choose that correctly from the list provided.

Well, at least once the crosswords are solved, that's it, puzzle complete and you can move on with your life... Except that there's a 9-letter compound word to infer somehow from the completed grids.

I hope this doesn't make things too difficult for you... (Or do I?!)

> **TASK: Solve the two crosswords below, and extract a 9-letter compound word from the result - this is the final answer to the puzzle. Before/while solving, you will need to 'repair' the broken clues by inserting the missing words from the provided list into the '[MISSING]' placeholders; each missing word should be used exactly once. You will also need to work out which clue in each pair corresponds to which crossword grid; a letter is provided in each grid to help you get started.**

Grids:

[image: Crossword grids]
<sub>[*Solve on Penpa+*](https://tinyurl.com/26j25zbm)</sub>

Missing words:

> ATMOSPHERE BIRD CARBONATED CELL CORAL DIAMOND DOCTOR ENVIRONMENTAL FAT FIREFLIES FOOT GOLDEN HEART HEAT HORSE LEAD LEGS LEGUME MAMMAL MONKEY NEWT ORGAN OX SALT SECOND SKY SONIC SPECIES SPHERE STARS STONES THRUSH TRIANGLE UNIVERSE WIND WORLD

Crossword clues:

> **Across:**
>
> 4. Elvis Presley song (1961): “---- -- ----- and make my [MISSING] go crazy” (4,2,5) / City in Siberia (11)
> 8. The juvenile stage of a [MISSING] (3) / Deity (3)
> 10. Member of Tolkien’s Fellowship (7) / Move one’s [MISSING] from a position in which one is placed on top of the other (7)
> 11. Embarrass (5) / “All ----- [MISSING] to Rome” (5)
> 12. [MISSING] character in *Aladdin* (1992) (3) / Greek letter (3)
> 14. Daughter of Jennifer Lopez (4) / [MISSING] water (4)
> 15. Xenophobic mutant race, enemies of the [MISSING] (6) / Written communication (6)
> 16. Kill (3) / Singer of 2014 international hit song containing the lyric, “I’m gonna fly like a [MISSING] through the night; Feel my tears as they dry…” (3)
> 18. “Goodbye” in Spain (5) / Sports brand with a double [MISSING] logo (5)
> 21. Greenlights (3) / Unexplained oddity seen in the [MISSING] (3)
> 22. Be gradually destroyed (e.g. by [MISSING]) (5) / Perfect (5)
> 23. Levy (3) / [MISSING] of long-haired domesticated cattle (3)
> 24. William ------, founder of an eponymous [MISSING] care company in 1906 (6) / University dissertation (6)
> 25. Race held in Epsom or Louisville? (4) / Home to [MISSING] Lake City (4)
> 28. Turf (3) / Natural order of the [MISSING] (3)
> 30. Sound made by a [MISSING] (5) / Entice (5)
> 31. Soft, creamy cheese, originating in Normandy (7) / Member of the [MISSING] family (7)
> 32. Ernie ---, former [MISSING] No. 1 golfer (3) / Hebrew letter (3)
> 33. Red blood [MISSING] (11) / Relating to fluids at rest (11)
>
> **Down:**
>
> 1. Shape of the shadow of a [MISSING]? (6) / Nuremberg events? (6)
> 2. 2016 Disney film (5) / [MISSING] slogan: “Reduce, -----, Recycle” (5)
> 3. Island nation situated northeast of the [MISSING] Triangle (5) / Manual in India? (5)
> 5. Violent disturbance of the [MISSING] (5) / Bladed weapon (5)
> 6. Unleavened flatbread (7) / Describing a [MISSING] with no lines of symmetry (7)
> 7. Make (11) / 1967 hit for the Rolling [MISSING] (4,7)
> 8. Member of a mystic Jewish sect in the [MISSING] Temple period (6) / Minority group neighbourhood (6)
> 9. Meetings to discuss completed missions (11) / Mineralised debris in a secondary lymphoid [MISSING] (6,5)
> 13. Heavily built wild [MISSING] with backswept horns (7) / ‘Three bodies’ Buddhist doctrine (7)
> 16. Not at home (3) / Species of [MISSING] native to East Asia (3)
> 17. Inquire (3) / Omnivorous [MISSING] in the family *Canidae* (3)
> 19. Further back (6) / Short [MISSING] sequences used by brands in advertising (6)
> 20. Music artist behind the 2009 hit, [MISSING] (3,4) / Pool user? (7)
> 26. Capital city of Nigeria (5) / Dusan _____, Serbian footballer who [MISSING] for Fenerbahçe (5)
> 27. ______ Stoichkov, [MISSING] Boot winner at the 1994 FIFA World Cup (6) / *Spinus spinus* (6)
> 28. West Virginia, or West Bengal? (5) / Non-SI unit of [MISSING] (5)
> 29. Lane where the Muffin Man resides? (5) / A term to describe a person with excess body [MISSING] (5)

Comment: Absolute pain you got here Stiv...

Comment: For 3 down; is the missing meant to be the triangle itself, not the missing you have right now?

Comment: @Stevo Nope, that clue is correct as currently written.

Comment: Mainly finished the crossword... However I don't know how to extract anything.

Comment: Actually I broke my own crossword :sob:

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Answers to the left grid:

> Across:
>
> 4. Elvis Presley song (1961): "---- -- ----- and make my [HEART] go crazy" **KISS ME QUICK**
> 8. The juvenile stage of a [NEWT] **EFT**
> 10. Move one's [LEGS] from a position in which one is placed on top of the other **UNCROSS**
> 11. "All ----- [LEAD] to Rome" **ROADS**
> 12. Greek letter **ETA**
> 14. Daughter of Jennifer Lopez **EMME**
> 15. Xenophobic mutant race, enemies of the [DOCTOR] **DALEKS**
> 16. Singer ..., "I'm gonna fly like a [BIRD] ..." **SIA**
> 18. Sports brand with a double [DIAMOND] logo **UMBRO**
> 21. Greenlights **OKS**
> 22. Perfect **IDEAL**
> 23. [SPECIES] of long-haired domesticated cattle **YAK**
> 24. William ------, founder of an eponymous [FOOT] care company in 1906 **SCHOLL**
> 25. Race held in Epsom or Louisville? **OAKS**
> 28. Natural order of the [UNIVERSE] **TAO**
> 30. Sound made by a [HORSE] **NEIGH**
> 31. Soft, creamy cheese, originating in Normandy **BOURSON**
> 32. Hebrew letter **YOD**
> 33. Relating to fluids at rest **HYDROSTATIC**
>
> Down:
>
> 1. Shape of the shadow of a [SPHERE]? **CIRCLE**
> 2. [ENVIRONMENTAL] slogan: "Reduce, -----, Recycle" **REUSE**
> 3. Manual in India? **SUTRA**
> 5. Violent disturbance of the [ATMOSPHERE] **STORM**
> 6. Unleavened flatbread **CHAPATI**
> 7. 1967 hit for the Rolling [STONES] **RUBY TUESDAY**
> 8. Member of a mystic Jewish sect in the [SECOND] Temple period **ESSENE**
> 9. Mineralised debris in a secondary lymphoid [ORGAN] **TONSIL STONE**
> 13. 'Three bodies' Buddhist doctrine **TRIKAYA**
> 16. Species of [LEGUME] native to East Asia **SOY**
> 17. Inquire **ASK**
> 19. Further back **BEHIND**
> 20. Music artist behind the 2009 hit, [FIREFLIES] **OWL CITY**
> 26. Capital city of Nigeria **ABUJA**
> 27. Spinus spinus **SISKIN**
> 28. Non-SI unit of [HEAT] **THERM**
> 29. A term to describe a person with excess body [FAT] **OBESE**

Answers to the right grid:

> Across:
>
> 4. City in Siberia **KRASNOYARSK**
> 8. Deity **GOD**
> 10. Member of Tolkien's Fellowship **ARAGORN**
> 11. Embarrass **ABASH**
> 12. [MONKEY] character in Aladdin (1992) **ABU**
> 14. [CARBONATED] water **SODA**
> 15. Written communication **LETTER**
> 16. Kill **OFF**
> 18. "Goodbye" in Spain **ADIOS**
> 21. Unexplained oddity seen in the [SKY] **UFO**
> 22. Be gradually destroyed (e.g. by [WIND]) **ERODE**
> 23. Levy **TAX**
> 24. University dissertation **THESIS**
> 25. Home to [SALT] Lake City **UTAH**
> 28. Turf **SOD**
> 30. Entice **TEMPT**
> 31. Member of the [THRUSH] family **REDWING**
> 32. Ernie ---, former [WORLD] No. 1 golfer **ELS**
> 33. Red blood [CELL] **ERYTHROCYTE**
>
> Down:
>
> 1. Nuremberg events? **TRIALS**
> 2. 2016 Disney film **MOANA**
> 3. Island nation situated northeast of the [CORAL] Triangle **PALAU**
> 5. Bladed weapon **SWORD**
> 6. Describing a [TRIANGLE] with no lines of symmetry **SCALENE**
> 7. Make **MANUFACTURE**
> 8. Minority group neighbourhood **GHETTO**
> 9. Meetings to discuss completed missions **DEBRIEFINGS**
> 13. Heavily built wild [OX] with backswept horns **BUFFALO**
> 16. Not at home **OUT**
> 17. Omnivorous [MAMMAL] in the family Canidae **FOX**
> 19. Short [SONIC] sequences used by brands in advertising **IDENTS**
> 20. Pool user? **SWIMMER**
> 26. Dusan _____, Serbian footballer who [STARS] for Fenerbahçe **TADIC**
> 27. ______ Stoichkov, [GOLDEN] Boot winner at the 1994 FIFA World Cup **HRISTO**
> 28. West Virginia, or West Bengal? **STATE**
> 29. Lane where the Muffin Man resides? **DRURY**

Filled-in grids:

> [image: soap operas and berries]

The answer:

> Across several answers in the left grid, we can read the words **[Crossroads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossroads_(British_TV_series))**, **[Emmerdale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emmerdale)**, **[Brookside](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brookside_(TV_series))**, **[Hollyoaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollyoaks)** and **[Neighbours](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbours)**. These are all **soap** operas.
>
>  Similarly, the words **goose**, **blue**, **rasp** and **straw** can be found reading downwards in the unchecked letters of the across clues in the right grid. These words can be combined with **berry**.
>
>  Putting these two together, we get the final nine-letter answer, **[soapberry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sapindus)**.

Comment: You've got all the parts, and the final answer is right there within reaching distance for you! You've found exactly what I wanted you to find hidden in the grids - I suggest you put them together and remember that this is a 'Science and *Nature*' themed puzzle... :) PS You can also include [the central vertical word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shepherdia) in your second grid...

Comment: Okay, so I'm looking for a word that fits both grids. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partridge_berry) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenleaf_(TV_series)) only fit one side of the story ...

Comment: Actually, you already have both parts of the word... Each grid was supposed to provide a hint towards one half of the compound word. If I tell you that it begins in 'S' and ends in 'Y', hopefully you'll know what it is... (On reflection, I should perhaps have been a bit clearer in describing how to extract the word...)

Comment: Of course I was Making Things Difficult for myself by calling the thing in the left grid by its formal long name. You've chosen an appropriate title for the puzzle ...

Comment: Haha, yes apparently so! That's as intended now though - thanks for solving :)